# How can I toggle a child when I hover over a parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asynchronous

Here's some sample HTML

```
<style> .icon {display:none;} </style>
<ul>
    <li>ABC <i id="abc" class="icon">x</i></li>
    <li>DEF <i id="def" class="icon">x</i></li>
    <li>GHI <i id="ghi" class="icon">x</i></li>
</ul>
```

I need to show `.icon` when I hover over its parent `li`.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
$('.icon').each().parent().hover(function() {
    $(this).children('.icon').toggle();
});
```

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with CSS too (although problematic in IE, since it has issues with :hover on tags other than A):

```
<style> 
.icon {display:none;} 
li:hover .icon {display:inline;}
</style>
```

Comment: Wow, that's a nice way to do it!  I think you deserve the credit for no script at all.

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to use `each` method, you can use `$(selector, context)`, try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('ul li').hover(function() {
        $('.icon', this).toggle();
   });
})
```

Comment: Very nice.  Worked like a charm.  Decided to give joquarky the answer due to solving it entirely with CSS.  But the selector, context is new to me so I'm grateful for your answer as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to show the icon only as long as you hover:

```
$('li').hover(

  // called on mouseenter
  function () {
    $(this).find('.icon').show();
  },

  // called on mouseleave
  function () {
    $(this).find('.icon').hide();
  }
);
```

This method is saver than to simply `toggle` visibility state in case events get lost..

Comment: Wow, you were right.  Toggle would lose events, especially when combined with a remove().  This is a great find.  Thanks.